# XMPPFramework over websocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, chat, xmppframework

We need to develop a XMPP based chat client. The only feasible iOS library that we found is XMPPFramework.

The next hurdle that we face is XMPP uses TCP connection, but our server has websocket endpoint.

For websocket we have socketRocket available in iOS. But we are not aware about all the features and any issues that might be with it to support what GCDAsyncSocket has in XMPPFramework.

What are the alternatives to achieve solution for above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I spent 3 weeks working on a POC and I didn't find any iOS library to do XMPP over Websocket
XMPPFramework is the best iOS XMPP framework but it's doing XMPP over TCP